# how to group array of objects by value in reactjs / javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, foreach, group-by

I have an array of object that have different values like

```
 items=[{id:1,category:"cat_1" , title:"My title 1"},{id:2,category:"cat_2" , title:"My title 2"},{id:6,category:"cat_1" , title:"Another title 1"},{id:1,category:"cat_3" , title:"My title 3"},{id:8,category:"cat_1" , title:"Third Title"},{id:2,category:"cat_2" , title:"Another title 2 "}]
```

I use array map to list the object and display them as

```
     {
     items.map((item) => (
        <h1>{item.category}</h1>
        <p>{item.title}</p>
    ))}
```

My question is how do i iterate the item so as it groups the items by category as follows

```
cat_1
- My title 1
- Another title 1
- My title 3

cat_2
- My title 2
- Another title 2

cat_3
-Third Title
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `.reduce`:

```js
const items = [{
  id: 1,
  category: "cat_1",
  title: "My title 1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  category: "cat_2",
  title: "My title 2"
}, {
  id: 6,
  category: "cat_1",
  title: "Another title 1"
}, {
  id: 1,
  category: "cat_3",
  title: "My title 3"
}, {
  id: 8,
  category: "cat_1",
  title: "Third Title"
}, {
  id: 2,
  category: "cat_2",
  title: "Another title 2 "
}];
const cats = items.reduce((catsSoFar, { category, title }) => {
  if (!catsSoFar[category]) catsSoFar[category] = [];
  catsSoFar[category].push(title);
  return catsSoFar;
}, {});
console.log(cats);
```

Comment: @TerryLennox: That is an understatement! In fact, `reduce` is a general iteration operation, *everything* you can do with a `FOREACH` loop (`for`/`in`, `for`/`of`, `Array.prototype.forEach`), you can do with `reduce`! Once you have `reduce`, you no longer need `map`, `filter`, `groupBy`, `sort`, etc. (except for readability and clarity, of course). There is a simple sketch of a proof on [the Wikipedia page for `fold`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality). So, `reduce` is not just "super powerful", it is in fact "all-powerful".

Comment: @JörgWMittag, but you could say the same thing about `forEach` and even plain `for` and `map` - the important part isn't using something that's sufficiently powerful ( http://qr.ae/RNMEGA ), but using something that's powerful enough *and* is semantically proper for what its effect is.

Comment: Well put @Jörg I'll check out the article!

Comment: @CertainPerformance: `map` is not general. It cannot change the length of the collection, for example, or return something that is not a collection. You cannot implement `sum` in terms of `map`, unless you abuse the fact that in ECMAScript, the mapping function can have side-effects and get access to the collection itself, thus mutating it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag My point was that you can use/abuse (for example) `map` to achieve something that's not maplike, just like you can use/abuse `reduce` to do something more suited to a method such as `forEach` `filter` etc.

Comment: for reducers with Object destructuring `+1`

Answer (score 5):

I use lodash in a lot of projects as a general utility belt. If you decide to do something similar -- it would be simple as:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  category: "cat_1",
  title: "My title 1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  category: "cat_2",
  title: "My title 2"
}, {
  id: 6,
  category: "cat_1",
  title: "Another title 1"
}, {
  id: 1,
  category: "cat_3",
  title: "My title 3"
}, {
  id: 8,
  category: "cat_1",
  title: "Third Title"
}, {
  id: 2,
  category: "cat_2",
  title: "Another title 2 "
}];

const groups = _.groupBy(data,  'category');

console.log(groups);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make CertainPerformance's answer a bit more concise:

```js
    const items = [{
      id: 1,
      category: "cat_1",
      title: "My title 1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      category: "cat_2",
      title: "My title 2"
    }, {
      id: 6,
      category: "cat_1",
      title: "Another title 1"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      category: "cat_3",
      title: "My title 3"
    }, {
      id: 8,
      category: "cat_1",
      title: "Third Title"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      category: "cat_2",
      title: "Another title 2 "
    }];
    const cats = items.reduce((catMemo, { category, title }) => {
      (catMemo[category] = catMemo[category] || []).push(title);
      return catMemo;
    }, {});
    console.log(cats);
```

Comment: how to render this in react

Answer (score 0):

Readability is important, but for anyone who's looking for a one-liner:

```
const groupedItems = items.reduce((ob, item) => ({...ob, [item.category]: [...ob[item.category] ?? [], item]}), {})
```